# Should the Feudalism and Neo-feudalism have separate tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I was considering adding the neo-feudalism tag but thought to ask here first.

They are distinct concepts but I predict it is nuanced and specialized enough that blindly making the tag will see resistance and debate. Well, here’s the debate in advance.

As a reference I will share ]my recent post]([Why can’t the everyman get housing without the Lords of America?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227185/why-can-t-the-everyman-get-housing-without-the-lords-of-america)) which has the confusion plain to see in my comments.

I will add [this answer to a question about advanced feudal societies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/162507/could-a-technologically-advanced-society-exist-as-a-feudal-monarchy/162520#162520) to the queue as well, because it seems to reflect the popular opinion about modern feudalism, but in fact points fairly plainly to what theoretically drives neo-feudalism in nations like South Africa and Somalia today.

Another point: The [feudalism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feudalism) tag info really doesn’t cover modern age at all.

Comment: Why not include your proposal for a [tag:neo-feudalism] tag in your question, to make it clear what you think it should be and how it different from plain old [tag:feudalism]?

Comment: What do you consider to be a) the definitions of feudalism & neofeudalism; and b) what ought to be distinguishing factors of the existing & proposed tags?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a need for a separate tag.

> The feudalism tag info really doesn’t cover modern age at all.

This is simply wrong.

The feudalism tag info states:

> For question about **worlds where the political structure resembles and portrays features of medieval times, including lack of a strong central power, fragmentation of nations into small-ish states with a rather weak national feeling**.

It's not the time that makes medieval-ish, but the political structure. As such there is no need for a neo-feudalism targeted to the modern age, because the existing tag already covers it.

Comment: If that is the definition of the tag `feudalism` then it is . . . strange. Ancient Greece had no central power, was fragmented into small states, and had a weak national feeling. It also was not feudal, like, not at all, not even a little bit. On the other hand, the Ottoman empire had a strong central leadership, was a large and powerful state, and was feudal.

Comment: @AlexP -- You can probably speak better to this, but a quick peek at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feudalism) reveals this definition for feudalism: *A social system based on personal ownership of resources and personal fealty between a suzerain (lord) and a vassal (subject). Defining characteristics are direct ownership of resources, personal loyalty, and a hierarchical social structure reinforced by religion.* I wonder if the tag itself needs to be revised?

Comment: @AlexP editing tag wikis is open to everybody, go ahead and make it better